# Node.js Express serving index.html instead of static file

Tags: node.js, express, assets

Im starting a node.js with express app, using angular. Everything was working fine while creating the app on cloud9.

I just released the app on my ec2 instance and now node always deliver index.html instead of my static file... When i look in chrome debug network, i see all js files loaded (status 200) but when i preview them, its my index.html file... The type of my js files is also set to text/html...

Here is my little server.js (no routing as i fake my angular data, so no call to the server for now...)

```
var express = require('express'),
path = require('path'),
http = require('http'),
fs = require('fs');

var app = express();

var logFile = fs.createWriteStream('./logger/express.log', {flags: 'a'}); //use {flags: 'w'} to open in write mode

app.configure(function () {
    app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
    app.use(express.logger({stream: logFile}));
    app.use(express.bodyParser()),
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
});

 /*app.get('/events', eventRoute.getEvents);
app.post('/events', eventRoute.saveEvent);*/

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function () {
    console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
});
```

As i said previously, everything is working fine on cloud9 (cannot try on local for now...).

Does anyone has a clue about what is going wrong?

Thanks

Dominic

PS: I forgot to mention that it is the same with my CSS file!

Edit: Here a little picture of what i mean!
[image]

And when i look at the preview of any file i get [image]

Edit2: I just deleted all my files and uploaded them again. Same problem! I really need help on this one please!

Fo live demo of the problem, hit [that site](http://adocrate.com)

Comment: How is jquery.min.js showing correct ? Also can you check if all the files in the public directory are valid and not copies of your index.html

Comment: jQuery.min.js is loading correct because it is load from cdn instead of being serve by my server. I will have a look as soon as possible to check if my js files are still like the original and not copies of index.html. (no ssh acces at job :/)

Comment: I juste checked and my JS / CSS file are ok. The contains what they sould contains. Anyone has an idea to solve this?

Comment: Are all files like that, I cannot see all from the screenshot. I don't see any problem in your express server. You said you faked angular data, are you intercepting all the links on the page, check your angular page/script.

Comment: Yes all the files are like that, except those loaded from CDN. My angular dont make any call for now. Just a few partial view filled with local data ($scope.client = {})... I dont see how it could make it happen... for now, i deleted all the file on the server and i am transfering it back to see if maybe there has been a problem while the initial upload!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well after a few hours of research about what can cause it, i finally found it!

The problem was not code related at all! I was hitting a new ec2 instance and i didnt route port 80 to my node.js app (81**).

I basically just runned this command and everything started working just fine.

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to 81**

Thanks you all

Answer (score 4):

Can you elaborate on what you mean by your 'static file' ?

on this line:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

you have express routed to serve all files in the 'public' dir as static files. By default, express.static will serve 'index.html' if that directory is called. since you're serving the 'public' dir to '/', it's delivering index.html.

EDIT: I'm not sure if this is the problem, but this part of the code is redundant:

```
http.createServer(app).listen()
```

you can just say:

```
app.listen([port], [callback]);
```

since calling express() created a server.
hope that helps.

Comment: By static file i meant my Javascript files and my Stylesheet file.

I have server.js in my root directory and then /Public/js /Public/css.

How can i make it so it serve index.html when calling '/' and then serve the js file?

Comment: I removed the http.createServer! It is, as you said, redundant! 

Unfortunatly, the problem is still not solved ...

Answer (score 0):

In your root folder having server.js / index.js file, add the following code -

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const path = require("path");
```

Sometimes the server.js file is not able to understand the location of build folder hence add the static location of build folder

```js
app.use(express.static('client/build'));

// This will render your frontend at http://localhost:PORT/
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
});

// To serve you api at http://localhost:PORT/api
app.get("/api", (req, res) => {
  res.send("This is API");
});

// After this add the required the port number

const PORT = process.env.PORT

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log("✅ Server running on port:",PORT);
});
```

Make sure the commands of calling functions are in this order -

1. app.use
2. app.get
3. app.listen

Command to run - node server.js